# Is it possible to mark a git commit as work-in-progress?

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag, git-bisect

I'm aware that there are various opinions and philosophies about whether or not all commits on the master branch should leave the project in a valid, working state. I'm not asking for these opinions.

For the sake of argument, let's assume that somewhere in the `master` branch history I identified a commit that is actually a work-in-progress commit, i.e. it doesn't build or it breaks other things. Since we are talking about history in the master branch, rebasing or amending (or anything that actually changes the commit) is not an option.

To warn other developers and to make it easy for an automated git bisect script to skip this commit, I want to somehow mark this commit as work-in-progress. How do I do this?

I have thought about using `git tag`, but since tags must be unique you would end up using tags like `wip/<some_unique_id>` which is an ugly hack in my opinion. Also, conceptually we do not want to treat this commit as a tagged commit, i.e. we probably never want to check it out, we may not want it to appear in the list of tagged commit points etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) to add notes to certain commits without touching their commit hash.

If you want to annotate `HEAD~5` with a note, do

```
git notes add HEAD~5 -m "better don't use this commit. It breaks the build"
```

Publish your notes with

```
git push origin refs/notes/*
```

Have a read of [ProGit](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/08/25/notes.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

In other hand, just to bring good practices to the conversation, I would say the described situation where you cannot rebase or amend, being on `master`, should never happen. Every commit merged on a shared branch (`master`, `develop`, whatever) should always be stable. I don't see any reason explaining why a WIP commit could not be on a dedicated branch.

In a preferable approach, you would, for example:

```
git checkout -b hotfix-branch
git add .
git commit -m "[wip] Fixing index route access"
git push origin wip-branch
```

Then, after finishing the work:

```
git commit --amend  # Let's reword to "[hotfix] Fixed index route access"
git push origin hotfix-branch --force
git checkout master
git merge hotfix-branch  # Fast-forward or not, etc., whatever
git push origin master
git push --delete origin hotfix-branch
git branch -d hotfix-branch
```

In this example (which can surely be improved, that's not the point), `amend` can be replaced by some `fixup`/`autosquash` if needed, but you get the painting. The point is to work on a dedicated branch, use Git to save unstable state through a WIP commit, then rewrite history before merging to shared branch to keep the `git log` clean.

One should never, as you said, rewrite history on a shared branch. This is why you don't want to put yourself in a situation where such a thing could even come to your mind. Always work on dedicated branches where rewriting history doesn't matter, and merge clean and stable commits on shared branches. (:

Comment: -1. This does not answer the question. The assumption of the OP's question was, that there _is_ a wip-commit on master. It doesn't help to say, that it should not happen, even if you are absolutely right about that ...

Comment: As I said in my first sentence, I was just talking about good practices, giving an alternative approach to a biased question. But you're right, that is not really a direct answer to the question, it could have been a comment. My bad. (:

Answer (score 1):

I never heard about such feature, so I created it :

```
# Commit current work as wip so that I can switch branch
function gitwip {
    git add -A && git commit -m wip
}

# Reset last commit if it is a work in progress
function gitrwip {
   lastCommitMessage=`git log --oneline -n1 | awk '{$1= ""; print $0}'`
   lastCommitMessage=${lastCommitMessage:1:30}
   [ "$lastCommitMessage" = wip ] && git reset HEAD~1 || echo "#$lastCommitMessage#[...]" is not a wip commit
}
```

The `gitwip` function prevent me from doing a `git reset HEAD~1` if the last commit is not a `wip` commit.

Comment: Where do I place these lines? What's `gitrwip`?

Comment: @RuudLenders This a bash function. You can put it in your terminals after your prompt. If you want this function to be here every time you log in with your terminal, you have to put it in your `.bashrc` (if you are using bash).

Answer (score 0):

We can mark the commit as work-in-progress in 2 methods:

1st you can use UI.

2nd approach, use command: `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%wip`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).